# C# how to add class's labels to form's control

Tags: c#, class, menu, controls

I'm making menu class that makes me easy to control the menus
For easy understand look at the image below 
[image]

If I want to make these menus, I create my menu class and add 7 menus to the class, set the text, set the color, set the position ...
Everything is fine, But I have a problem with controls.
When I created the menu class in the Form1.cs I don't know how should I add the labels to Form1's controls.
The way I thougth is make the class get the form's control and add the labels in the class.
So is there any ways to get the parent class's controls in it's child class?

like

main class example

```
namespace Tetris
{
    public partial class Form_Start : Form
    {
        public Form_Start()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Menu menu = new Menu(10,postion_x,postion_y,str_arr);
        }
    }
}
```

menu class example

```
class menu
    {
        Label[] lab;
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        int num, start_x, start_y, x_interval, y_interval;
        public create_menu(int value, int start_x, int start_y, int x_interval, int y_interval, List<string> str)
        {
            num = value;
            lab = new Label[num];
            start_x = this.start_x;
            start_y = this.start_y;
            x_interval = this.x_interval;
            y_interval = this.y_interval;
            str = this.str;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (Label label in lab)
            {
                label.Text = str[count];
                label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(start_x + x_interval * count, start_y + y_interval * count);
                count++;
                Parent.Controls.Add(label); // <- I want to know this code
            }
        }
}
```

If you have any better ideas or know the other ways please tell me. thank you

-------------------------------------------------
By sending the controls to the class, I added the labels to the form.

```
create_menu menu = new create_menu(3, 20, 20, 0, 10, menu_str, this.Controls);
public create_menu(int index, int start_x_, int start_y_, int x_interval_, int y_interval_, List<string> str_, Control.ControlCollection ctrl)
{ ctrl.Add(label[i]); }
```

Is there any better ideas??

Comment: If I got you correctly - You have a menu control with few labels on it to show a menu sort of structure. When you add an instance of that menu control onto a form `form1` then all the labels present on your menu control will get added to your form. Have I interpreted it correctly? In this case your menu control will be parent of menu labels and form1 will be parent of menu control. So what exact problem you are facing here?

Comment: @RBT yep but I want to know how class get the control of it's parent

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your class a bit. Simply inherit your menu class from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class as shown below:

```
class menu : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
        //....your entire code for menu class
}
```

Now whenever you add your menu to a windows form `Form1` you can access its parent using `this.Parent` (for getting its parent control) or `this.ParentForm`(for getting its parent windows form) syntax. You can use this syntax inside any of the methods defined inside your `menu` class. E.g. I can do something like this in one of your methods:

```
public create_menu(int value, int start_x, int start_y, int x_interval, int y_interval, List<string> str)
{
    //other code
    Console.WriteLine(this.Parent.Name);
}
```

Hope this helps!